Node-canvas: Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
I try to build an api that get a base64 string of a PDF file and convert it to JPG file.
I am using "pdf-to-img" library which use canvas and it work on my local machine (windows 10).
When I deploy my node server to aws ECS on ubuntu 22 server and try to upload a PDF file,
I get the following error:
"Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/src/my_app_name/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libpixman-1.so.0)"
According to node-canvas documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas, each machine (ubuntu in my case) required additional packages.
So in my build.sh file I add the following packages:
# Install native modules
echo "install canvas dependencies..."
apt-get install -y build-essential libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev

# Install app packages
echo "build packages..."
npm i --only=prod

It seems that this file is already installed on my ubuntu server - I add this check:
echo "List dynamic dependencies of canvas.node..."
ldd node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node

and the result (part of it) is:
libpixman-1.so.0 => /codebuild/output/src789052830/src/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f0e08007000)
libcairo.so.2 => /codebuild/output/src789052830/src/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f0e07f11000)
libpng16.so.16 => /codebuild/output/src789052830/src/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f0e07edb000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0e0810d000)

which means that this file: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (which is a part of libc6 package), is installed by default (maybe in the wrong place..)
I also run this:
echo "Check if ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is installed"
ls -l /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

and got:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 May  6  2024 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

which means that this file: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is installed and directed to the path /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 .
The documentation of node-canvas also says that:

Compiling



If you don't have a supported OS or processor
architecture, or you use --build-from-source, the module will be
compiled on your system. This requires several dependencies, including
Cairo and Pango.

There are many discussions about that issue in the web that recommended to use commands like
"--build-from-source" or "npm rebuild" but It's not so clear where and when to use it, I tried almost every possible combination like:
cd node_modules/canvas
npm install --build-from-source
cd ../..

or:
npm rebuild canvas --update-binary

and nothing worked.
what am I doing wrong?
versions:
node: 20,
ubuntu: 22,
pdf-to-img: 4.2.0

did you try node 22 yet?

no, how can it help?

you are installing a binary module on a node version that is soon going to hit End of Life. so... using the current LTS version which is 22, sure can help..

also, you are trying to install a canvas version that's two years old. maybe give the current release candidate via the tag 3.0.0-rc2 a try.

I don't use canvas directly but through the "pdf-to-img" package which use the 2.11.1 version (latest for now) of canvas, upgrading the canvas (if possible) may lead to unexpected behavior, but I can try it
